# Hide fields until a value in a radio button is selected

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, jquery

My requirement is that i have a radio button on a New Item form with the values of Yes/No.  If No is selected, i need to be able to have 10 fields appear (single line of text) so that the end user can fill in additional information (up to ten line items).  How might i accomplish this in SharePoint 2013/Online?

I believe it's possible to make the single line of text fields required if they are on the form using OOTB validation, but what if i want those fields to be hidden until the radio button is selected?  I would imagine this would be a javascript/jQuery solution?

[image]

EDIT: Added screenshot of form.

EDIT: Updated with solution.

Thanks to everyone who replied for your insights.  I ended up creating a New Item form in SP Designer and using jQuery to hide the fields and show them when the "Short all items on PO?" field equaled "No".  I changed the field type to choice/drop down as i'm not sure how to code this using radio buttons.  Everything i've tried has failed within SP as far as grabbing the selected value of a radio button.

I initially tried to wrap all 10 fields in a div/tr/td/span (tried just about everything) but this kept throwing a web part error or just wouldn't hide the fields.  I ended up adding a class to each of the ten fields and hiding them with jQuery.  For those interested, below is the code i'm using which is accomplishing what i need.  Originally i started the script by just hiding the fields by using the class selector in jQuery.  I ran into an issue when i would forget a required field as the form would then reload and hide the fields again.  Adding the if statement in the beginning to check the value corrected this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var shortVal = $("select[title='Short all items on PO?'] option:selected").val(); 
        if(shortVal === "Yes" || shortVal === ""){          
          $(".lineItems").css("display", "none");
          }
          $("select[title='Short all items on PO?']").change(function(){
              var shortVal = $("select[title='Short all items on PO?'] option:selected").val();
                if(shortVal === "No"){
                  $(".lineItems").css("display", "");
                  }
                    else if(shortVal === "Yes"){
                      $(".lineItems").css("display", "none");
                  }
            });
        });           
    </script>
```

Comment: Nate, you could try using jQuery. Are you using InfoPath or just OOTB SharePoint forms? Post some screen shots of what you have so far.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the form, but there's really not much to it.  I would like to use OOTB SP forms and not have to deal with InfoPath.  I'd like to have the form pull up without all the Item 1, Item 2, etc. lines showing.  If they click No on the "Short all items on PO?" field, it would then display the ten lines.

Comment: If you have SharePoint Designer, you could look at the suggestion below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to achieve this

Option 1:
Open your list in SharePoint designer and create a new form based on existing new item form template. Set the form you created as a default form. Now modify this form to meet your requirements by adding javascript/jQuery. You can keep the 10 single line of text fields inside a div and hide it on page load. Write a change event for radio button and hide or display the div based on radio button value

Option 2:
Edit the existing NewForm.aspx page and add a content editor webpart to the page and add all your javascript/jQuery to the content editor web part.

Option 1 would be a easier way, because you can edit the html of the form too. For example, putting all the 10 fields inside a div and hiding it would be much more easier than hiding all 10 fields separately using jQuery.

Comment: Option 3: Create a CSR file (Client Side Rendering) and attach it to the List Form webpart with a JSLink